# Visual Studio 2008 crashing after converting 2005 SSRS Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We recently migrated to SharePoint 2010 and I am updating a few reports. The .rdl files were developed in Visual Studio 2005. I am converting them to VS 2008 and deploying them to the new SP site.

Some of the reports convert just fine. Others will open just fine, but when I attempt to open the data source or preview a report it crashes.

First a message windows pops up saying Visual Studio has stopped working and gives this error message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  9.0.30729.1
  Application Timestamp:    488f2b50
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_3ab9
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16915
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49d10
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 000ce903
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 3ab9
  Additional Information 2: 3ab916335f95035652d49d418d47682b
  Additional Information 3: 7e6c
  Additional Information 4: 7e6c28d0938d251b2561c357b5643f43
```

If I debug it I get the message: "Unhandled exception at 0x7738e903 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted."

If I hit continue I get no more error message and the task executes successfully (opening the data source in this case)

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: Make sure you disable any 3d party extension that could be installed in your Visual Studio. A buggy extension may cause any kind of problem.